# Runtime of brute force string-matching algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, string-matching

I've written a small, quick (to write, not to run!), algorithm for string matching in Python:

```
def bruteMatch(n,m):
    for i in range(0,len(n)-len(m)+1):
        if n[i:len(m)+i]==m:
            return(i)
```

Would the runtime for this algorithm be O(nm)? I'm comparing it to the worst-case runtime for the Horspool string-matching algorithm, which is also (nm). I guess my confusion stems from the fact that my algorithm appears initially as O(n) runtime as it simply iterates through the input n, using the indices as inputs to a slice notation equality statement? Thoughts?

Comment: You probably already know this, but it bears pointing out for any other readers that Python already has a `str.find` function that does exactly this, and is ~10x faster than this function.

Comment: Yes, this is merely for academic function. The Horspool algorithm I mentioned, in-and-of-itself is much faster than the bruteMatch function I wrote.

Comment: @Turtle-in-a-bash-shell check my answer, your function have some issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worst case is O(nm), yes. Because, you see, the `==` test tests each character in each string, which could take as long as the length of the shortest string in the equality test.

Comment: OK, thank you, I guess the stem of my confusion was viewing the equality as one statement when in reality it is checking each character. Simple and effective answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This does indeed take O(n*m) time. You run the loop (n-m) times, and the string comparison itself takes (min(n,m)) time. This is fine while either n or m is very small, but consider a worst case where m=n/2:

The loop is executed (n-n/2) times, and the comparison takes (n/2) time, a total of (O(n^2)) time - not so great!

If performance is important, and the search string is large, consider using a hash-based algorithm such as [Rabin–Karp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
def bruteMatch(n,m):
    for i in range(0,len(n)-len(m)+1):
        if n[i:len(m)+i]==m:
            return(i)
```

1. `for i in range(0,len(n)-len(m)+1)` will loop `len(n)-len(m)+1` times
2. `if n[i:len(m)+i]==m` compare all characters in n `from i to len(m)+i` with m

**Example 1**

```
n = "Hello"
m = "Jello"
len(n)-len(m)+1 = 4-4+1 = 1

range(0,1)

i=0
if n[0:4+0] == m ~ n[0:4] == m[:] ~ "Hello" == "Jello"
FALSE
```

**Example 2**

```
n = "Hi"
m = "Jello"
len(n)-len(m)+1 = 2-4+1 = -1

range(0,-1) ~ *LOGICAL ERROR*
```

**Example 3**

```
n = "Hello"
m = "Hi"
len(n)-len(m)+1 = 4-2+1 = 3

range(0,3)

i=0
if n[0:2+0] == m ~ n[0:2] == m[:] ~ "He" == "Hi"
FALSE

i=1
if n[1:2+1] == m ~ n[0:3] == m[:] ~ "Hel" == "Hi"
FALSE

i=2
if n[2:2+2] == m ~ n[0:4] == m[:] ~ "Hell" == "Hi"
FALSE
```

**Conclusion**

Your code is going to compare `n[0:z]` for `z` in range `(0, len(n)+1)` for `len(n)-len(m)+1` times:

```
If len(n) == len(m) then check n == m
Else if len(n) > len(n) then return check m is in [ n[0:len(m)], .., n[0:len(n)] ]
Else if len(n) < len(m) then Error: Invalid range
```